# Removing /index.php/ from URLs in Joomla 3.x leads to Error 404

Tags: joomla-3.x, joomla-3.4

I want to remove /index.php/ from the URLs in Joomla 3.x. I enabled "Use URL Rewriting" in the configuration. It removed the /index.php/ but leads to error 404. Except for the home page.

Comment: Rename htaccess.txt to .htaccess but no changes... Anything that will work I highly welcome

Comment: Your comment only alerted me because I am the only user to comment under your question.  To respond to the answerers, leave a comment under their answers -- this way they will receive a notification.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on the host of your website, there can be several solutions.

First, as already mentioned, rename the htaccess file.

If this proves to be unsuccessful:

1. Look into the system information tab and be sure that you're on an apache system and not on nginx. Because htaccess only affects Apache. Otherwise, you need to configure nginx.
2. If you're on Apache, check the rewrite base within the htaccess and remove the #. Or have a call with your hosting service provider to be sure that there is no other configuration necessary for the rewrite base.

Comment: Welcome to JSE, Holger.  Thank you for contributing!  Please take our [tour] and see if you can add value to any other questions.

Answer (score 0):

Rename htaccess.txt to .htaccess

Comment: This answer has been auto-flagged as Low-quality.  Please try to be more generous about what this does and why it is a good idea.  I realise you are making a very basic/intuitive/self-explanatory suggestion, but it role models better posting behaviours and stands to empower/educate more researchers if you can explain your solution.

Answer (score 0):

1. Rename htaccess.txt to .htaccess (as @Midhat said)

   > htaccess is needed to make your urls friendly. It comes with a ."txt"
   >   extension   by default.
2. Make sure your server has mod rewrite on

   > To enable mod rewrite open your `httpd.conf` file (in your server
   >   folder) search for `mod_rewrite`. If there's any "#" in front of
   >   `mod_rewrite`, take it out and save the file
3. Make sure your httpd.conf is correctly configured

   > it may be hard to find the correct configuration for the `httpd.conf`
   >   file, so after following the first two steps above, and you still get
   >   the error, i suggest you either changing your local server (if it's a
   >   local host) or contacting your hosting service to check the server
   >   configuration